# Google sheets formula to get a score based on weightages

Tags: gsheets

I have a google sheet (Alignment form responses)(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19nQ427RyA1_qyTyTNds2ZcYudLkFRicir901VudAJFQ/edit#gid=1879436751) consisting of 4 tabs(Sheet1,Sheet2,Comparison and Parameters).

Sheet 1: consists of form responses from both auditor and ops.
Sheet 2: consists of form responses from only the auditor
Comparison: Here the form responses of both the auditor and the ops is compared to check which parameters are aligning and a certain weightage is given to both of them
Parameters: Consisting of parameters sub-parameters and it's respective weightages (Consider only the sub-parameters and it's weightages)

**Condition:**

If the auditor has selected 2 sub-parameters and the ops has selected only one, and that one sub-parameter matches with one of the sub-parameters submitted by the auditor then the score for both auditor and ops should be given equal score, since one of the sub-parameters match.

For example:
In Sheet 1:

Auditor filled as : sub-parameter 1 (weightage:100), sub-parameter 2 (weightage:50)
Ops Filled as : sub-parameter 2 (weightage:50)

In Sheet 2:
Auditor Filled as : sub-parameter 1 (weightage:100), sub-parameter 2 (weightage:50)

In Comparison tab:
Scores for both should be 50% as one sub-parameter is matching

**Requirement:**

Need a google sheets formula for the above condition

I tried to compare the responses in sheet1 and sheet 2 in the comparison tab to get the score but I wasn't able to get a breakthrough.

If anyone is trying to access and try to get an answer kindly ping me in hangouts at (saketh.v8@gmail.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula to you can achieve the condition:

```
=IF((COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A, A2, Sheet1!B:B, B2) > 0) * (COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A, A2, Sheet2!B:B, B2) > 0), 1, 0) * B2
```

Comment: I tried to use the above formula, but an error appeared where the Sheet1!B2:B in the formula is a text hence multiplication is not possible.